# How's frequent pattern mining in data mining?

Tags: data-mining, sequential-pattern-mining

I am reading a paper [Frequent pattern mining:current status and future directions](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10618-006-0059-1.pdf).

---

From this paper I learned that a lot of people did some interesting jobs in this field. But this review is published in 2007. And as the size of data becomes bigger and bigger, in my opinion, frequent pattern mining which based on sparse data may not compete with Neural Network anymore?

---

Hope someone can tell some recent news about frequent pattern mining.

Comment: There isn't any; it had its day back when data science used to be called data mining (hence the name). If you're especially interested [here's a monograph](http://charuaggarwal.net/freqbook.pdf) from 2014, whose preface states _While the field has reached a relative level of maturity..._

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. But what about recommendation system? I mean it quite do some things with similar goal of pattern mining. But it looks quite different. Maybe it's parametric??

Comment: @WillCai Are you asking about how people are using `Frequent pattern mining` in the DeepLearning/BigData era, right?  Pl ask a pointed question at the end of the post, else it would look like speculation, and might end up getting closed :)

Comment: @Dawny33 Sorry, I just want to ask about is Frequent pattern mining still have something interesting on which we can do some research.... In fact these days i am doing a project about it and i want to focus on the theoretical part. Unfortunately Emre said it has reached a relative level of maturity...Um, it's not a good news for me....

Comment: Look into ranking instead. It's hot, challenging, and not mature.